# Using mock.patch gives me AttributeError("<module 'package1''> does not have the attribute 'myfunc'"?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, python-unittest

I'm trying to use mock.patch to mock a couple of functions. I've cut my example down for readability. Here is test.py with my test case:

```
from unittest import mock
import pytest
@mock.patch("package1.myfunc")
def test_myfunc(mymock):
    inst1 = MyClass()
    inst1.myfunc()
```

And here is my source code in mycode.py

```
import package1
class MyClass:
    def__init__(self):
        pass
    def myfunc(self): #wrapper
        package1.myfunc()
```

Am I doing this correctly? Why am I getting an Attribute error? The reason why I didn't do anything else with "mymock" is because I simply want the function called to do nothing. Do I still need to add a return value to it?

Detailed error message:

```
exc_info = (<class 'AttributeError'>, AttributeError("<module 'package1' from '/.../site-packages/package1/__init__.py'> does not have the attribute 'myfunc'"), <traceback object at 0x7f2b86392640>)
patching = <unittest.mock._patch object at 0x7f2b86a479d0>
    @wraps(func)
    def patched(*args, **keywargs):
        extra_args = []
        entered_patchers = []
   
        exc_info = tuple()
        try:
            for patching in patched.patchings:
>               arg = patching.__enter__()
/.../python3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/mock.py:1247:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
/.../python3.7/unittest/mock.py:1319: in __enter__
    original, local = self.get_original()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
self = <unittest.mock._patch object at 0x7f2b86a479d0>
    def get_original(self):
        target = self.getter()
        name = self.attribute
   
        original = DEFAULT
        local = False
   
        try:
[name]             original = target.__dict__
        except (AttributeError, KeyError):
            original = getattr(target, name, DEFAULT)
        else:
            local = True
   
        if name in _builtins and isinstance(target, ModuleType):
            self.create = True
   
        if not self.create and original is DEFAULT:
            raise AttributeError(
>               "%s does not have the attribute %r" % (target, name)
            )
E           AttributeError: <module 'package1' from '....'> does not have the attribute 'myfunc'
/.../python3.7/unittest/mock.py:1293: AttributeError
```

Comment: You forgot the `self` argument in `myfunc`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Sorry, thanks. Typo

Comment: Apart from that, it looks ok to me - can you show the callstack? (assuming that `myfunc` is implemented in `package1.py`, of course)

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Right, it is implemented there. I added in additional error messages. Thanks for the help

Comment: well, the error message says that `package1` does not have that function. Can you show how it is defined in `package1.py`?

Answer (score 11):

From python's own documentation you can see that the decorator is to be used this way:
`@patch('package.module.ClassName.attribute', sentinel.attribute)`

source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html

It seems like you're missing the ClassName in this case. You should be using

```
@mock.patch("package1.MyClass.myfunc")
```